# Concat Regex on Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the data from a table where the row values are comma-separated strings, like this: `5,10,16,25,7` I'm also using a `LEFT JOIN`, so I need something like this:

```
// ...

SELECT ... s.`other_thing`

LEFT JOIN `something` s
ON w.`whatever` = REGEXP CONCAT('(,|^)', s.`id`, '(,|$)')

// ...
```

I need to get something like this: `(,|^)5(,|$)` on `ON`

**EDIT:** I solved this with a simple `LIKE CONCAT('%', s.id, '%')`

**EDIT 2:** If you want to concat the Regex, you can use: `REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(',s.id,')(,|$)')`

Answer (score 2):

I strongly discourage this data model.  Your next question is likely to be about performance -- and there is really no hope.  You should have a junction/association table for the lists, rather than storing multiple values in a string.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad design decisions.  If this is the case, MySQL has a function to help:

```
SELECT ... s.`other_thing`
FROM x LEFT JOIN
     something s
     ON find_in_set(s.id, x.really_bad_list_format) > -
```

Comment: Yep, this is not the best data model I've worked with... I'm using `LIKE CONCAT('%', s.id, '%')` now, thanks for your answer!